# How Can you periodically backup to Google Drive on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, backup, google-drive

I need to backup folders automatically and periodically to Google drive from Windows 10.

The official Google Drive app supports sync mode, this is not suitable because if a file is deleted from Google drive, it also deletes it from the local computer.

Other than sync mode, Google drive only supports manual backup.

Is there a way to automatically periodically backup to Google drive?

Comment: Sync mode IS suitable. What you mention is a non-issue with a very simple solution: Don't delete from the Google Drive.

Comment: Google Drive can also be accessed via Google Apps Script. I haven't used it, but [Is there a way to Archive files and folders to a specific folder in Google Drive and keep folder path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59091508/1115360) shows an example.

Comment: It seems like the new Google Drive Desktop App now mounts the Google Drive folder as a disk in your "This PC" with a drive letter. If you see this drive letter (I'm not using it), you may use any backup software to copy the folders.

Comment: Google Drive is **not** a backup solution. And misusing it as such for anything important is a bad idea. https://www.backupify.com/blog/why-google-drive-isnt-backup

Comment: For why sync mode isn’t suitable. If your Google drive gets hacked they can not only delete your backups, but also your original local copies.

Comment: It should be noted google also likes to lock you out of your account then provide literally ZERO human support. So it's a very bad idea to rely on them for backup.